# How to geneate asm and bytes from a benign and malicious software?

Tags: security, analytics, disassembly

I've been working on a project about analyzing a random software.
But I've failed on generating automatically an PE file from samples.
I've tried using radare2 but I could just get a asm file contained a small part of the whole,not like IDA PRO which can simply generate a whole PE file.
If  using IDA PRO,the problem is that I am not able to get an fully-functional version and generating them automatically.
Other than that ,I use python3 with the following code.

```
import os
import glob
sample_path="/home/cape/Documents/DikeDataset-main/files/malware/*"
for i in glob.iglob(sample_path):
    print(i)
    sha_name=i.split(".")[0]
    print(os.path.getsize(i))
    with open(i, 'rb') as fr:
        with open(sha_name+'.bytes', 'w') as f:
            contents = fr.read()
            counter16=0
            counterendl=0
            #f = open("/home/cape/Documents/DikeDataset-main/files/"+i+".bytes", "w")
            for single_character in contents:
                if counterendl%16==0:
                    list=[]
                    listtest=[]
                    #print(hex(counterendl))
                    #print(hex(counterendl).split('x')[1])
                    #print(len(hex(counterendl).split('x')[1]))
                save_digits=hex(single_character)
                list.append(save_digits.split('x')[1])
                listtest.append(single_character)
                counter16+=1
                counterendl+=1
                #print(counter)
                if counter16 ==16:
                    #print(list)
                    #print(listtest)
                    for j in range(16):
                        if int(list[j],16)<16:
                            f.write("0"+list[j])
                        else:
                            f.write(list[j])
                            #print(list[j])
                        f.write(" ")
                        #print(" ")
                    f.write("\n")
                    counter16=0
```

using`with open(path,'rb') as read`opening the file and transfprming each character into hexadecimal digit by `hex()`.Finally append the digit ,inserting space digit by digit .
But my tutor said it might not work on analyzing.
Currenly I have no idea what or how to do .

I wonder if there're way using radare2 or other tool to accomplish my demand.
Or wheather there's any improvement I can do in my code.